# Copy filtered table data and paste into another workbook

Tags: excel, copy-paste, excel-tables

I am trying to create a weekly timecard using a copy of data filtered from a worksheet table and pasted into the Timecard file, and then using "Save" to the new timecard file name. I'm missing something somewhere having tried so many different solutions offered here, but now just at a loss on what to do for a resolution.

```vb
Public Sub Create_Timecard()
'
' Create a Timecard from user input box containing open TaskDataBase entries
'
Dim WorkflowRTE_07 As Workbook
Dim TimecardRTE0 As Workbook
Dim Tasks As Worksheet
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
'
Dim WorkflowRTEPath As String
Dim TimecardRTEPath As String
'
Dim TimecardWEDate As String, TimecardEstimID As String, TimecardFilename As String
Dim TimecardTable As ListObject
Dim Lastrow As Long
'
'>>> Define workbooks paths
WorkflowRTEPath = "C:\Users\Deb\Documents\_EXCEL\WorkflowRTE\WorkflowRTE_07.xlsx"
TimecardRTEPath = "C:\Users\Deb\Documents\_EXCEL\WorkflowRTE\TimecardRTE0.xlsx"
'
'>>> Set a reference to the target Workbook and Sheets use Workbooks.Open(Filename)if closed
Set TimecardRTE0 = Workbooks.Open(TimecardRTEPath)
Workbooks("WorkflowRTE_07").Activate '>>> Macro being run from this workbook so Open not required
'
'>>> Get user input to name weekly estimators individual timesheet
TimecardWEDate = InputBox("Timecard Week-ending Date required", "Enter the timecard week ending date....", "YYYYMMDD")
TimecardEstimID = InputBox("Timecard User ID required. Enter the Esimators Timecard ID ie: Estim99", "Create Timecard for Estimator", "Key Timecard ID here....")
TimecardFilename = TimecardWEDate & "_" & TimecardEstimID
MsgBox ("Creating timesheet - " & TimecardFilename)
'
With Tasks
    '>>> Remove any filters from the sheet
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
'
    '>>> Get last row of database
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox ("last row of database is " & Lastrow)
'
    '>>> Specifying the complete address is the key part
    With Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Lastrow, 15))
'
    '>>> Specify .AutoFilter Field:=YOURFIELDNUMBER, Criteria1:=YOURCRITERIA
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TaskDataBase").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=TimecardEstimID
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TaskDataBase").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="=In Progress", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Not Started"
'
    '>>> Now copy and paste each section (column) of the data
    'Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Lastrow, 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("TimecardRTE0").Worksheets("Timesheet").Range("C2")
    'Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Lastrow, 2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("TimecardRTE0").Worksheets("Timesheet").Range("D2")
    'Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(Lastrow, 5)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("TimecardRTE0").Worksheets("Timesheet").Range("B2")
    End With
End With
End Sub
' Then add code to save the new timecard
```

Comment: Please edit your post, and give each line of code a 4-space indent. That will cause automatic script formatting to kick in, improve readability *tremendously*, and increase the odds of a useful answer!  

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll try to do better next time. Thank you to Scott Craner who cleaned it up.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also specify what exactly is the problem! What specific are you getting and how exactly does it vary to your expectations? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
    '>>> Specify .AutoFilter Field:=YOURFIELDNUMBER, Criteria1:=YOURCRITERIA
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TaskDataBase").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=TimecardEstimID
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TaskDataBase").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="=In Progress", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Not Started"
'
'>>> Copy range and Paste to destination sheet
        Set Destin_range = Sheets("Mapping2").Range("A2")
            Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(lastRow, 5)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            Destin_range.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        Set Destin_range = Sheets("Mapping2").Range("B2")
            Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            Destin_range.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).